# I wish I could upload zip file on my blog

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I was wondering to upload my zip file to my "wordpress" blog, but unfortunately I could not figure out anything,Is there any possible way to do that?
Any help will be appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy if you have FTP access. If you are uploading it so other can download, I will suggest you to keep it in Media folder.

Comment: Thanks Nizam kazi :) It really helps me .